# Not able to insert CAFÉ in mysql, even after setting encoding correctly

Tags: java, mysql, sql, encoding, utf-8

I inserted the word `CAFE` in `name` field mySQL table.

Unexpectedly, I get a row containing `CAFE` when I execute below statement

```
SELECT * FROM myTable where name='CAFÉ';
```

, which is wrong. In my use-case `CAFE` shouldn't be equal to `CAFÉ`

I think I set all the encodings correctly on server and client side:

**Server side:**

By modifying `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` I get below

```
mysql> show variables like "%character%";show variables like "%collation%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Client Side:**

```
      connect = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+serverName+"/" + 
 dataBaseName + "?characterEncoding=utf8&user=" + userName + "&password=" + password);
```

p.s. there are many duplicate questions similar to this, but none of them answering specific to what I am running into.

Comment: Long shot, but did you also try the solution described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5629121/3080094 ?

Comment: +1 Using `BINARY` after `WHERE` worked i.e. it was able to differentiate between CAFE and CAFÉ.  Thank you. Now, I have to figure out how to insert CAFÉ in table without tripping unique constraint on name.

Comment: You can make the column of VARBINARY type, but then you will have to be extra carefull with character sets (all clients need to use the same). As alternative, these answers might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/458544/3080094
http://stackoverflow.com/a/264389/3080094

Comment: These are good information, please post it as an answer.

Comment: Glad it worked out, I've posted an answer (after you tested the solutions, thanks for that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collation `utf8_general_ci` (`_ci` stands for Case Insensitive) does not only make `e` equal to `E`, but also makes `E` equal to `É`. To make a select statement case sensitive, you can use the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5629121/3080094) answer:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable where BINARY name='CAFÉ';
```

If you want to make data in column `name` always case sensitive, use a case sensitive `_bin` collation as shown in the answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264381/is-there-a-way-to-force-case-sensitivity-in-mysql-rails-for-a-single-find) question. E.g. when you create a table, use:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
...
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @vanOekel comments

adding `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin` while creating the table solved my problem

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (     
     name CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT uc__name UNIQUE (name)     
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Now in my table I can have both `CAFE` and `CAFÉ` without tripping the unique constraint on `name` field.